How to list all event listeners in Firefox developer tools?
How to list all event listeners in Firefox dev tools? (GUI or console)

List all event listeners on window object.
Firefox does not have Chrome's window.getEventListeners.
List all event listeners on whole document.
It seems that Firefox inspector only list events listener bound to a single element.

